# Probability of 2 people standing next to each other

Tags: probability

Tony, Angela, and four of their friends are at an amusement park. They all get in line for a roller coaster. If the six of them line up at random, what is the probability that Tony and Angela are standing beside each other?

I know that the answer is 1/3 but how do you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: There are $\binom 62$ equally likely outcomes for which of the six positions in line the two named persons end up at. $5$ of these have them standing next to each other.

Answer (score 3):

Henning Makolm's answer will be faster, but you can also count all the possibilities. There are $6!$ ways of arranging everyone in line. There are $5 \cdot 2! \cdot 4!$ ways to arrange everyone with Tony and Angela next to each other: $5$ choices of which two spots to choose, $2!$ ways to arrange Tony and Angela in those spots, and $4!$ ways to arrange the other four in the remaining spots.