# permutations 2 people stand next to each other in link

Tags: probability

I am sorry for posting a duplicated question but I have looked through the comments of this post and couldn't understand the answers.

[Probability of 2 people standing next to each other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581842/probability-of-2-people-standing-next-to-each-other)

would someone please help me understand this concept? Thank you,

Comment: How much do you know about probability and combinatorics? Are you familiar with combinations and what they mean?

Comment: I am currently enrolled in a probailites course. And  I am facing difficultes understanding a problem similar to this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given 6 people you can put them 6! different ways in a line. The first person has 6 available places the second only 5 the third has 4 and so on... So 6x5x4x3x2x1=6!
Then, for the two of them to be together you have two option (wether or not they switch places) and given one combination (say they are in 1st and 2nd positions) you can put the other friends in 4x3x2x1 different ways in the rest of the line. Now, you have 5 places where they can be together so multiply the probability by five and you get the answer.
$\frac{5.2.4!}{6!}$

Comment: thank you, shouldn't we use factorial 2 since we want to consider switching the places of the two people?

Comment: Yes it's just 2!=2